# Scrolling texture on quad is laggy

Tags: scroll, unity-game-engine, textures, shader

What could be the reason of lag while I scroll a simple texture on a quad using Unity 4? The lag is not consistent, the scroll works for like 3 or 4 seconds smooth and than comes the lag and so on.

Here is the code

```
    public float speed = 0.01f;

    manager.scroll_speed = Mathf.Repeat(Time.time *speed, 1);   
    renderer.sharedMaterial.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(manager.scroll_speed, 0));
```

What should I do to get rid of the lag?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying sharedMaterial will change the appearance of all objects using this material, and change material settings that are stored in the project too. I'm guessing you wanted to do this on purpose but maybe scrolling textures on a whole bunch of objects is just not efficient. If it's just one object then just use `renderer.material`. Actually try using `renderer.material` anyway and just having different instances of the script